Disable javascript content assist
I would like to disable this window taking up the entire screen width which pops up after typing the commma:

The file is opened with "Generic Text Editor", which I guess is the misleading name for "Wild Web Developer", but I'm not sure.
There doesn't seem to be anything in the settings anywhere.
I'm running Eclipse 2023-12 (4.30.0).
Thanks

